# Series expansion for `ProductLog[-1,x]`

Tags: series-expansion

Is there a way to get Mathematica to expand
`Series[ProductLog[-1, x], {x, -Exp[-1], 1}]`?
I'm on Mathematica 12, and it just returns `Out[] = ProductLog[-1, x]`.

I can expand the main branch `Series[ProductLog[x], {x, -Exp[-1], 1}]=-1+Sqrt[2 E] Sqrt[x+1/E]-2/3 E (x+1/E)+O[x+1/E]^(3/2)`. The `-1` branch should have the same expansion, except without the alternating signs. (See e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1628.pdf )

I wonder if Mathematica simply doesn't know that this simple expansion exists, or if I'm doing something wrong?

(I can also write `Series[x Exp[x], {x, -1, 3}] // InverseSeries`, but that gives a weird result full of `System'SeriesDump'z$561645`'s.)

Comment: Try: `Series[ProductLog[-1, x], {x, -Exp[-1], 5}, Assumptions -> x > -1]` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Awesome! Thanks! Is there a similar trick to get `PadeApproximant` to work? It also works on the principal branch but not on $W_{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mariusz says, you can give [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) an assumption:

```
Series[ProductLog[-1, x], {x, -Exp[-1], 1}, Assumptions -> x > -1] //TeXForm
```

> $-1-\sqrt{2 e} \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{e}}-\frac{2}{3} e
>    \left(x+\frac{1}{e}\right)+O\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{e}\right)^{3/2}\right)$

For [`PadeApproximant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadeApproximant), you can instead use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming):

```
Assuming[
    x > -1,
    PadeApproximant[ProductLog[-1,x], {x, -Exp[-1], {1, 1}}]
] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\frac{301}{540} e \left(x+\frac{1}{e}\right)-\frac{14}{45} \sqrt{2 e}
>    \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{e}}-1}{\frac{83}{540} e \left(x+\frac{1}{e}\right)-\frac{31}{45}
>    \sqrt{2 e} \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{e}}+1}$

Comment: Thank you! A last one: How do I get `Series[ProductLog[-1, x],{x,0,1}]` to produce reasonable results (without imaginary numbers in it)? any `Assumptions` or `Assuming` statements I've tried don't appear to help.